# Need to pass field value of external object into field value of custom object on OnLoad function

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can anyone help me to get the field (TotalValue__c) value of an External object (Revenue__x) into the field value (TotalValue__c) of a custom object (project__c)?

Can we achieve this through an Apex class or LWC?

Comment: Ramya, do you want to automate this? Choose Apex. Or do you want to make a user to key this in? Use LWC. Please explain more in detail how your process is to look like. E.g. how the External Object is updated, the frequency etc.

Comment: Through Salesforce connect Odata2.0, got one external object(RevenueSum__x). I have field (Revenue__c) in external object.similarly I have a custom object(Pipeline__c) in which I have with the same field name(Revenue__c)... Need to get field value of External object into custom object. Can you help me on how to get this